# PhantomJs can access remote sites via PHP shell_exec but not local sites

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, phantomjs

I am having an issue with the callback for [page.open](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html) not running when I run phantom JS on a local server page using PHP's using shell_exec(). If I run phantomjs via commandline on a local URL then the callback does fire.

PHP Script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_write_close();
$result = shell_exec('phantomjs server.js ' . $_GET['url'] ); 
echo $result;
```

JS script

```
/**
 *  PhantomJs server for calling webpages & processing JS
 *  returns page content
 */

var args = require('system').args;
var address = args[1];
var page = new WebPage();

var renderPage = function(){

    page = require('webpage').create();
    var myArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        url_str = myArgs[0];

     console.log('accessing:'+url_str);

    page.onError = function(msg){console.log('js error');}

    /**
     * From PhantomJS documentation:
     * This callback is invoked when there is a JavaScript console. The callback may accept up to three arguments:
     * the string for the message, the line number, and the source identifier.
     */
    page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg, line, source) {
        console.log('console> ' + msg);
    };

    /**
     * From PhantomJS documentation:
     * This callback is invoked when there is a JavaScript alert. The only argument passed to the callback is the string for the message.
     */
    page.onAlert = function (msg) {
        console.log('alert!!> ' + msg);
    };

    /**
     * Handle Redirection
     */
    page.onNavigationRequested = function(url_sub_str, type, willNavigate, main) {
        if (main && url_sub_str != url_str) {
            url_str = url_sub_str;
            console.log("redirect caught");
            page.close();
            setTimeout(function() {
                renderPage(url_str)
            },1);
        }
    };

    page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
        console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
    };

    /**
     * Open the web page and run RRunner
     */
    page.open(url_str, function(status) {
        console.log('here');
        if (status === 'success') {
            console.log(page.content); 
            phantom.exit();         
        } else {
            console.log('failed');          
            phantom.exit();
        }
    });
};


address = 'http://local.wordpress.dev/test.php'; /* does not work via shell_exec */
//address = 'http://local.wordpress.dev/'; /* does not work via shell_exec */
//address = 'http://www.inboundnow.com/'; /* works via shell_exec */
renderPage(address);
```

When I call my php script the js outputs this into the body:

```
accessing:http://local.wordpress.dev/test.php
```

- I am running on a [VVV-Apache vagrant](https://github.com/ericmann/vvv-apache) machine.
- If I try to access an .html file while using the PHP method I get a successful response.
- If i try and access a local dummy php file that echos out some content it does not work using the PHP method.

Comment: what is output of `echo $result` ?

Comment: So, it's probably a problem for PhantomJS resolving the domain name. Have you tried it with the local IP that is setup by VVV?

Comment: I added echo $result content to the original post. I have been able to output the content of http://local.wordpress.dev/readme.html when using the PHP method, so the domain name resolves in this case. It only has trouble with accessing .php files.